# Install bcrypt without Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, node-gyp

I'm trying to install `bcrypt` via `npm` and I'm getting a `Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.8 install script.` error.

I'm on Windows 8 x64, node ver 0.10.29.

Looking at `bcrypt`'s dependencies tells me I need `node-gyp`, which apparently needs visual studio 2012 and python. For real? Do I really need to install a full IDE that I'm not going to use for this one node module?

Is it the compiler `node-gyp` is after, or some other small component from VS I can install that will do the trick?

Would love any suggestions for how to get this working with minimum possible extras.

Comment: According to the documentation, you need to have at least VS Express installed.  If you are wondering why that is, or if you can install a small subset of the functionality instead you would probably have better luck asking on their github: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Comment: A lot of compiled extensions, not surprisingly, depend on a compiler. You might be able to find a pure JavaScript alternative, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As previously mentioned, you can install VC++ Express (and the Windows SDK) for free. However, if you are really that bothered by it, you could use a `bcrypt` API-compatible module that is [implemented in pure javascript](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js), however you will see a performance hit.

I should also note that there are many (useful) modules on npm right now that require compilation, so chances are you'll be getting more use out of the compiler (in the future) than you think.

Comment: Very much liking the no dependencies part. Password encryption and decryption is supposed to be slow anyway right?

Comment: How could anybody be bothered with installing Visual Studio and the Windows SDK on his Windows Server right? Sure let's have that GB's of crap sitting on my server. Pure JS compiled and run by V8 is pretty fast. Here's a [pure JS solution for bcrypt](https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs). I'd like to see a benchmark.

Comment: There are at least [benchmarks for the pure-JS module I linked to](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js/wiki/Benchmark), comparing against the compiled addon.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Also, you don't need to install Visual Studio, etc. on your production system(s), only on your development system(s). You can then deploy the compiled addon to your Windows server.

Comment: @mscdex How can you do that ? complile addon then distribute it on production machine ? Any clues? Thanks !

Comment: @ArnaudJanssens When you successfully compile an addon, there is a `.node` file in `build/Release/` (or `build/Debug/` if you built with the debug flag set). All you need to do is copy that file with your project, since that is what you `require()` to get at your addon.

Comment: @mscdex Thanks, I have this file but no idea on how to make "require" use this. Do you have any links providing more informations ? Note that i'm totally newbie about node addons compiling, requiring etc.